# Find a formula for n so that U(P, f) - L(P, f) < $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Using the formulas for U(P, f) and L(P, f), I find that

U(P, f) - L(P, f) = $\Sigma$ $M_i(x_{i+1} - x_i)$ - $\Sigma$ $m_i(x_{i+1} - x_i)$, and through some manipulation and substitution I get $\frac{b-a}{n}(f(a)-f(b))$, and if I want this to be less than $\epsilon$ then $n > \frac{(b-a)(f(a)-f(b))}{\epsilon}$.

However, I'm not sure what to do so that my formula for n doesn't depend on the function f(x).

Comment: Your solution is correct. Of course $f$ must appear in the formula since, for every $c$ and $P$, $U(P,cf)-L(P,cf)=|c|(U(P,f)-L(P,f))$.

Comment: ??? Did you read my first comment?